# Running .net core on linux standalone

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have started to work on a web service (web api) with .net core and visual studio 15.

My goal is to develop the service on windows and then deploy it on an offline linux pc (The only way to put files on the linux pc is with with an usb flash drive).

Im having trouble with finding documentations or guides on how to accomplish this. Most of the info out there is talking about azure and remote virtual servers which Is irrelevant.

Any information about how I can disturbute to linux and install the .net framework on a standalone linux will be very helpful

Comment: You will need to install the linux runtime on your windows machine (using dnvm) and then publish your application with the runtime and then the application will be x-copyable. I think you will want to use CoreClr and not the full framework - otherwise to run your app you will have to install Mono on the target linux box.

Answer (score 0):

you can read about how to install .NET Core on Linux on this pages:
https://get.asp.net/OtherDownloads
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/getting-started/installing-on-linux.html

To deploy an app to Linux I usually use a source code management like Git (push to Git from windows and pull from Git on Linux).
FTP to the Linux machine could be another option, creating an install package or just use a USB flash drive

Comment: Thanks alot for your reply ! But im afraid its not very helpful;
I have read thoose guides about installing, the problem is that as I have mentioned, the linux pc's which
I need to install .net on have ZERO www access, and thoose guides kind of relay on have that access on some point 
(which is why it is a problem installing)

Comment: Secondly, about the deploying part, lets say that I do get the source code on the linux machine,
I still have no idea how to deploy and couldn't find any guides out there that are not
outdated or relay on www connection. Im not even sure what the source code can help me with
when visual studio is not for linux so I don't really see how this can help me deploy in either case

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000161/docker-container-with-asp-net-core-libraries/36000330#36000330). Basically you need to publish your application with the

```
dnu publish -o ./deploy
```

command. It will allow you to package your application along with the required packages for distribution.

Using this should allow you to drop that output folder on any machine with .NET Core. You will be able to run your web from the output path without downloading packages from NuGet.